# How should you divide a service layer method into testable chunk?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, tdd

```
exports.sendFeedbackServiceProviderMethod = function(req, res, next) {

    var articleId = req.body.articleId
    var commentId = req.body.commentId
    var action = req.body.action
    var meta = req.body.meta

    var Target
    var targetId
    if (articleId) {
        Target = Article
        targetId = articleId
    }
    else if (commentId) {
        Target = Comment
        targetId = commentId
    }

    //1. find the target
    //Note: will refetch when need to send json, since feedback has been changed
    Target.findById(targetId).exec(function(err, target) {
        if (err)
            return next(err)
        if (!target)
            return next(helper.getGeneralError('target does not exist'))


        //2. find the feedback
        var criteria = {}
        criteria['statusMeta.createdBy'] = req.user
        if (action === 'like' || action === 'dislike' || action === 'unlike' || action === 'undislike')
            criteria['type'] = {$in: ['like', 'dislike']}
        else if (action === 'share' || action === 'unshare')
            criteria['type'] = 'share'
        if (articleId)
            criteria['target.article'] = articleId
        else if (commentId)
            criteria['target.comment'] = commentId

        Feedback.find(criteria).exec(function(err, feedbacks) {

            if (err)
                next(err)
            if (feedbacks.length === 0) {
                //3. Feedback does not exist, create it
                var newFeedback = new Feedback()

                if (action === 'like' || action === 'dislike' || action === 'share') {
                    newFeedback.type = action
                    newFeedback.status = 'normal'
                    newFeedback.statusMeta.createdBy = req.user
                    if (articleId)
                        newFeedback.target.article = targetId
                    else if (commentId)
                        newFeedback.target.comment = targetId
                    if (meta)
                        newFeedback.meta= meta
                }

                newFeedback.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        return next(err)

                    //4. save to target feedbacks list
                    target.feedbacks.push(newFeedback)
                    target.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            return next(err)

                        //5. save to user feedbacks list
                        req.user.feedbacks.push(newFeedback)
                        req.user.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                return next(err)

                            //6. done
                            //Note: send the target!
                            //Note: refetch target and populate, since its feedbacks have been changed
                            var query = Target.findById(targetId)
                            populateUsersForQuery(query)
                            populateFeedbacksForQuery(query)
                            query.exec(function(err, target) {
                                if (err)
                                    return next(err)
                                return res.json(target)
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
            else {
                //3x. Found the feedback, update it
                var feedback = feedbacks[0] //must be length 1

                if (action === 'like' || action === 'dislike' || action === 'share') {
                    feedback.type = action
                    feedback.status = 'normal'
                    feedback.statusMeta.updatedBy = req.user
                    feedback.statusMeta.updatedDate = new Date
                }
                else if (action === 'unlike' || action === 'undislike' || action === 'unshare') {
                    feedback.status = 'deleted'
                    feedback.statusMeta.deletedBy = req.user
                    feedback.statusMeta.deletedDate = new Date
                }
                if (meta)
                    feedback.meta= meta

                feedback.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        return next(err)

                    //4x. done
                    //Note: send the target!
                    //Note: refetch target and populate, since its feedbacks have been changed
                    var query = Target.findById(targetId)
                    populateUsersForQuery(query)
                    populateFeedbacksForQuery(query)
                    query.exec(function(err, target) {
                        if (err)
                            return next(err)
                        return res.json(target)
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I have this piece of code and it's huge and I was wondering how to go about testing it. Should I divide it into smaller pieces and how should I do this, or should I leave it as it is and test the whole chunk. Also, I am not sure what's the standard way of testing a service layer method, do we just test the route as a whole like here:

```
describe('POST /user', function() {
  it('user.name should be an case-insensitive match for "john"', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .post('/user')
      .send('name=john') // x-www-form-urlencoded upload
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect(function(res) {
        res.body.id = 'some fixed id';
        res.body.name = res.body.name.toLowerCase();
      })
      .expect(200, {
        id: 'some fixed id',
        name: 'john'
      }, done);
  });
});
```

Or should I check the state of every object modified? Could you tell me how to set up the unit testing for the method above and how I should divide it to make testing easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `sendFeedbackServiceProviderMethod` has too many responsibilities violating the SRP ([Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). You should definitely consider refactoring using for example the [Split phase technique](https://refactoring.com/catalog/splitPhase.html). After you do that you can test the functions independently. All these `find`, `findById`, `update` and `save` functionalities indicate different actions hence different functions probably. You can keep your current test as an acceptance test of course and after refactoring this huge function create the appropriate unit tests.

Your function also has a lot of abstraction levels which is violating SLA ([Single Level of Abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction)). There are high level concepts mixed with low level details which indicates to refactoring.

I would suggest you to convert your comments to self explaining functions and unit test them as well.

Comment: How do you think I should divide them up, and where should I put them? Should I put them in the services folder, in the same file (feedbackProvider)? What's the standard way of doing this?

Comment: If the functions are commonly used you should put them in a common component (or folder), otherwise you should keep them near the used service.  My approach of division would be to turn those comments into functions, one function and unit test at a time.

Comment: so I can put it in the same folder as the other service functions even if they are not called by the controller?

Comment: There is no standard way really, these decisions are about how you architect and design your product. There are a lot of approaches and different teams have different convections. I would prefer to have my "helper" functions near the place where I use them for better trackability.

Comment: However, if you produce functions that they are querying  the database (or any other storing device) you can introduce a repository layer (folder) where all the queries take place.

Comment: Repository layer? Shouldn't it be DAO layer? I have some issues with the naming conventions. I don't know if you can use DAO if you're using a ODM like Mongoose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202497/discussion-between-alexis-pavlidis-and-deliguy).